# Cannot delete user in SAMBA

Tags: linux, samba

I'm using GADMIN-SAMBA program on Linux for administering Samba server, and in the list of users in the "Users" tab in the first row there is the following data:

```
"WARNING" "Group name not found" "No value has been set" "No value has been set"`
```

When I select this row and click "Delete" button, the following message appears:

> Could not remove the samba user: WARNING

And the row remains unchanged.

I could not find any records with a user named "Warning" in `/etc/smb.conf`, `/etc/samba/smbusers` files and in `/var/samba/profiles` directory. How can this record be removed from the users list?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask on [sf] or [Unix.se]

Comment: @Mike W - before posting the question I checked for the "samba" tag and saw quite a few questions about Samba server. I this is not right forum for such questions, I guess the question could be moved, but I don't know how to move questions. Maybe administrator can move it if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem is (1) you have no users added to the SAM database, or (2) that you do not have the following SAM files available for `pdbedit` to read:

```
/etc/samba/private
    passdb.tdb
    secrets.tdb
```

Since samba makes use of `pdbedit -L` to generate a user list to be displayed. If you either (1) have no users, or (2) do not have the SAM files available, you will generate an error attempting to access that information. It appears that GADMIN is taking the first line returned (the error) as the user and attempting to display it. You cannot delete this.

Comment: There are several users listed in the users list, including the user added by the Samba itself by default - smbguest. Those two files exist, but they are located not in etc/samba/private/, but in /var/lib/samba/ (on Debian Wheezy). I copied them into /etc/samba/private/, but the WARNING row didn't disappeared. :(

Comment: Al, it appears that it is looking for group information. Can you check from the command line. su to root and then `pdbedit -L` to simply list the users in the SAM file. That will tell us whether it is really a stray user or if there is a problem with GADMIN. (you can also try removing the extra files you copied. Your config should properly set your private directory which can be in /var as well as /etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The warning was caused by an incorrect value for paramater 'printing' (the value was set to 'none'). I changed it to CUPS and WARNING disappeared.

Comment: Sometimes this old dog stumbles into a correct answer :)  Glad I could help.